# Trying to make multi dropdown menus in single div but it's not working as expected

Tags: html, css

When I try to hover the mouse over one of the movies buttons both get activated. Can anyone suggest how to get rid of this error?

What is the problem with the code below?

```css
.navi {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Odibee Sans', cursive;
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navi li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

.navi li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Odibee Sans', cursive;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="verse.css">
  <title>error</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navi">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <li><button class="dropbtn">Movies</button></li>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Hindi</a>
          <a href="#">English</a>
          <a href="#">Multi-Audio</a>
          <a href="#">Dual-Audio</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <li><button class="dropbtn">Movies</button></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Hindi</a>
            <a href="#">English</a>
            <a href="#">Multi-Audio</a>
            <a href="#">Dual-Audio</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: you want multi-level drop down menu?

Comment: I checked your code and you have created only 2 drop downs one on top of the other

Answer (score 1):

You have named the same classes for both buttons you can change the name and make different function in css for each button so the menu will show different.